# Reference function of outer module

Tags: julia

I work on a numerical code solving two closely related problems. The following seems a good code structure to me:

```
module Problems

common_function(i) = println("Solving problem ", i)

module Problem1
solve() = common_function(1)
end # module Problem1

module Problem2
solve() = common_function(2)
end # module Problem2

end # module Problems
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work: running `Problems.Problem1.solve()` results in `ERROR: common_function not defined`. Can this be fixed?

Remark: I have more than just one function per module such that replacing the `Problem1` module with a `problem1_solve()` function would not be a very nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 1.0, you have to import from the [relative path](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Relative-and-absolute-module-paths-1) to the parent:

```
module Problems
common_function(i) = println("Solving problem ", i)

module Problem1
    import ..Problems: common_function
    solve() = common_function(1)
end # module Problem1

end # module Problems
```

This also works with `using ..Problems`.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: In version 1.0, this solution fails with `LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Problems not found in current path`.  See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52623251/1346276) for an update.

If submodules want to use functions of the parent module, they have to import them in the same way as unrelated modules have to.

```
module Problems
common_function(i) = println("Solving problem ", i)

module Problem1
    import Problems: common_function
    solve() = common_function(1)
end # module Problem1

end # module Problems
```

Deeper down the hierarchy of modules you can use

```
import ...Problems: function
```

where a single dot would refer to submodules, two dots to "sibling" modules and here three dots to the parent module with the name Problems.

As a side remark: The structure you are using looks a bit like you are coming from object oriented programming a background and used to work with inheritance. Maybe think again if you can structure your problem using multiple dispatch and abstract types.

Comment: You are right, I could define an immutable class `Problem1`, a constant `one = Problem1()` and `solve(::Problem1)` to be called as `solve(one)`. But is this really nicer than the module based solution?